# Removing a vertex of Petersen graph

Tags: tkz-collection

How can we remove the vertex "e" of Petersen graph and replace with three vertices? 
[image]

I used for drawing Petersen this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,bezier]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,euscript,graphicx,tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,tkz-berge}

\usepackage{caption}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]

\GraphInit[vstyle=Art]

\grPetersen[RA=5, RB=3]
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with `\grPetersen`. With these macros you can draw some famous graphs but if you want an incomplete graph you need to use macros from `tkz-graph` or macros that I use to build the "famous graphs".
Here you can draw the sub graph ijfgh then is possible to place the other vertices